# Android: Adding ability to take and delete multiple photos in one View, and then display multiple photos in another View

Tags: android, camera, photo

Trying to accomplish the following:

1. The first view needs to let the user take one or more photos from their camera (optionally from their gallery). The user should also have an easy way to delete individual photos. I suppose they could skip adding a photo.
2. The photos (0 to many) are displayed in another view to the user's friends.

I have it working with a simple ImageView, but this is only one photo. How can I have a user easily take multiple photos, and then easily delete them afterwards? I found the deprecated Gallery object but I do not believe the new Horizontal Scrolling View is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options for this:

1. Easy option:  Use `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` in horizontal orientation.  This won't align the image edges with the view when flinging the way `Gallery` does; if you're okay with that, then this is an easy solution.
2. Harder option:  Use `ViewPager` (with a regular `PagerAdapter`, not `FragmentPagerAdapter`).  `ViewPager` will "latch" the edges the way `Gallery` does.  The tricky part here is:  `ViewPager` can't size height by `wrap_content`.  If you know the aspect ratio of the images and how many images you want in a row, then you can use those numbers to set the specific height of the `ViewPager` and determine what value to return in the override of `PagerAdapter.getPageWidth(int position)`:

   ```
   // returns the width of a page as a percentage of the ViewPager width
   @Override
   public float getPageWidth(int position) {
       return 1F / (float) numImagesVisible;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up partially solving this, but still have some issues with sizing and ratio. See my follow up question here:

[Keeping the aspect ratio of ImageViews in a LinearLayout in a HorizontalScrollingLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986903/keeping-the-aspect-ratio-of-imageviews-in-a-linearlayout-in-a-horizontalscrollin)